# git prompting for password since updating to 2.36.1

Tags: git, gitlab

we have been using git for years with a local gitlab installation.  We have ssh keys setup, so a simple `git push` would not prompt for credentials.

since updating to 2.36.1, we are now being prompted for a password on `git push`.  trouble is, we have MFA enabled, so providing the password doesn't work.

I don't know if this is relevant, but we were also warned that the repository was owned by someone else and followed the suggestion to `git config --global --add safe.directory *foldername*`

I've tried adding a new RSA ssh key and it hasn't helped.

any ideas?

Comment: what OS are you running ?

Comment: The `safe.directory` bit is not relevant. What do matter are: (1) URL; (2) host OS; (3) more stuff depending on the answer to (1).

Answer (score 1):

A password or MFA (meaning using a token as a password) should only be relevant for an HTTPS URL.
For an SSH one, you might need to deal with a passphrase, if your private key was created encrypted.

So check first what `git remote -v` returns inside your repository.
If it is actually an HTTPS one, check the output of `git config --global credential.helper`: it might have cached an obsolete password for your GitLab account.

Answer (score 1):

doing a verbose test with

`ssh -vT git@my.domain.ac.uk`

showed that my rsa key was being attempted and that git was falling back to password.

I added a new ed25519 key with

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519`

and it works!  so the new version of git doesn't like my old RSA key?

EDIT:  even though I added a new RSA key and *thought* I had configured ssh to use it, the verbose test showed that it wasn't being tried.  So either it doesn't like RSA keys at all, or a new RSA key would have worked just as well if I'd given it the default name.

Comment: @bob mark this reply as the answer to the question :)